# Azure Functions HttpTrigger Keys in AKS

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-aks, azure-http-trigger

I am hosting my Azure Functions as containers in my AKS cluster. Some of my functions have HTTP Triggers, and I don't want them exposed publicly (although security is not a huge concern so I also don't want to roll my own token authentication in there). These functions have never been deployed to Azure App Services, so there is no "Function App" and no "Function Name" that I can use to get a token (other than the Function Name that I put in the attribute on the methods in my code).

How can you access authorization keys for Azure Functions that are hosted in AKS?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by setting `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType=kubernetes` and reference your custom key via secret `AzureWebJobsKubernetesSecretName=my-key-secret`. This was introduced by this PR which documents that quite well: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/4462

Comment: Are you aware of any examples/samples online to reference for this beyond the incomplete snippets linked in the PR and issues linked to that PR?